# How to achieve blur/frost/fibrancy background effect on views (NOT ON IMAGES) like on the Instagram app

Tags: android, instagram, blur, uivibrancyeffect

This was marked as duplicate incorrectly here by someone that clearly did not read the question in full, despite being a very small question in terms of text: [How to achieve blur/frost/fibrancy background effect like on the Instagram app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151983)

Instagram has a nice background blur effect that works over images and even videos.

**THAT BLURRY SECTION CAN BE MOVED UP AND DOWN AND THE RESPECTIVE BACKGROUND IS CORRECTLY BLURRED EVEN THOUGH THE VIEWS UNDER IT ARE NOT MOVING! THIS IS NOT ABOUT MAKING AN IMAGE BLUR, BUT THE CONTENTS BEHIND A SPECIFIC VIEW.
IT ALSO WORKS WITH VIDEOS BEHIND THE VIEW, NOT JUST STATIC IMAGES.
WHEN THE SECTION IS MOVED UP AND DOWN, ANYTHING BEHIND IT DOES NOT MOVE, BUT TURNS BLURRY**

[image]

**I have been trying to find out how this can be replicated, but ALL I COULD FIND WERE JUST WAYS TO BLUR IMAGES, NOT THE BACKGROUNDS OF VIEWS THAT ARE OVER OTHER VIEWS**

How can I achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a library would be the easiest way to achieve this, check out this one:

https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView

Comment: Perfect! The linked 500px library also appears to do exactly the same thing, thanks a lot.